# Microsoft Graph API add member to group failed with duplicate member add

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I tried to add a member to the group using the following request via Axios.

```
curl --location 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group_id}/members/$ref' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {token}' \
--data-raw '{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{member_id}"
}'
```

Every time I try to add a new user, I am getting the following error.

> One or more added object references already exist for the following
> modified properties: 'members'.

I listed all the users before sending this post request and check for the user/member id. If member is not available to the group then I am invoking this post request. Though I am getting the same error. Its adding the member to the group but responding with `400 - Bad Request`.

My List all members of the group query is,

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group_id}/members/microsoft.graph.user?%24select=id' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {token}' \
--data-raw '{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{member_id}"
}'
```

Javascript code,

```
// Check if the targetId is present in the response
 const isIdPresent = response.value.some(user => user.id === req.user.sub); 

if (!isIdPresent) {
   // Add user to group

}
```

Comment: Could you share more code? especially with the check that the member is not available?

Comment: @user2250152 Added code.

Answer (score 0):

I have one group named **`SriGroupDec`** in my tenant with **members** like this:

[image]

In my case, I used below code to add a member to the above group via Axios:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const clientId = 'appId';
const clientSecret = 'secret';
const tenantId = 'tenantId';
const groupId = 'groupId';
const memberToAddId = 'userId';

const getToken = async () => {
  try {
    const tokenResponse = await axios.post(
      `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
      `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`,
      { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }
    );
    return tokenResponse.data.access_token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error obtaining access token:', error.response ? error.response.data.error : error.message);
    throw error;
  }
};

const addMemberToGroup = async () => {
  try {
    const accessToken = await getToken();

    const checkResponse = await axios.get(
      `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/${groupId}/members/microsoft.graph.user?$select=id`,
      { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}` } }
    );

    console.log('Check Response:', checkResponse.data);

    const isMemberAlreadyAdded = checkResponse.data.value.some(user => user.id === memberToAddId);

    if (isMemberAlreadyAdded) {
      console.log(`Member with ID ${memberToAddId} is already in the group. Ignoring the request.`);
      return;
    }

    const addResponse = await axios.post(
      `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/${groupId}/members/$ref`,
      { '@odata.id': `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/${memberToAddId}` },
      { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}` } }
    );

    console.log('Member with ID ${memberToAddId} added successfully:', addResponse.data);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response && error.response.status === 400 && error.response.data.error.code === 'Request_BadRequest') {
      console.log(`Member with ID ${memberToAddId} is already in the group.`);
    } else {
      console.error('Error adding member to the group:', error.response ? error.response.data.error : error.message);
    }
  }
};

addMemberToGroup();
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where user added successfully to group like this:

[image]

When I ran the code again, I got the **response** saying *"Member with ID xxxx is already in the group. Ignoring the request"* as user is already added:

```js
const axios = require('axios');

const clientId = 'appId';
const clientSecret = 'secret';
const tenantId = 'tenantId';
const groupId = 'groupId';
const memberToAddId = 'userId';

const getToken = async () => {
  try {
    const tokenResponse = await axios.post(
      `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
      `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`,
      { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }
    );
    return tokenResponse.data.access_token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error obtaining access token:', error.response ? error.response.data.error : error.message);
    throw error;
  }
};

const addMemberToGroup = async () => {
  try {
    const accessToken = await getToken();

    const checkResponse = await axios.get(
      `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/${groupId}/members/microsoft.graph.user?$select=id`,
      { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}` } }
    );

    console.log('Check Response:', checkResponse.data);

    const isMemberAlreadyAdded = checkResponse.data.value.some(user => user.id === memberToAddId);

    if (isMemberAlreadyAdded) {
      console.log(`Member with ID ${memberToAddId} is already in the group. Ignoring the request.`);
      return;
    }

    const addResponse = await axios.post(
      `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/${groupId}/members/$ref`,
      { '@odata.id': `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/${memberToAddId}` },
      { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}` } }
    );

    console.log('Member with ID ${memberToAddId} added successfully:', addResponse.data);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response && error.response.status === 400 && error.response.data.error.code === 'Request_BadRequest') {
      console.log(`Member with ID ${memberToAddId} is already in the group.`);
    } else {
      console.error('Error adding member to the group:', error.response ? error.response.data.error : error.message);
    }
  }
};

addMemberToGroup();
```

**Response:**

[image]